# AngularJS nested directives are inserted outside their supposed parent element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble understanding how nested directives work with AngularJS.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('myTable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<table class="table table-query" ng-show="queries.length">',
                '<thead>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<th class="query-name">Name</th>',
                        '<th class="query-status">Status</th>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</thead>',
                '<tbody>',
                    '<my-row ng-repeat="query in queries track by $index"',
                             'query="query">',
                    '</my-row>',
                '</tbody>',
            '</table>',
        ].join(''),
        scope: {
            queries: '='
        },
        controller: function() {
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
        }
    };
});

app.directive('myRow', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<tr class="query query-status-{{query.status}}">',
                '<td>{{ query.name }}</td>',
                '<td>{{ query.status | uppercase }}</td>',
            '</tr>',
        ].join(''),
        scope: {
            query: '='
        },
        replace: true
    };
});
```

Can someone explain to me why the `tr` are diplayed outside the `tbody`?
What I simply want to do is nest a row directive inside a table directive. I'm pretty sure I'm missing a `ng-transclude` somewhere but where? I've checked `angular-bootstrap` and they seem to play a bit with `compile` function. Any help is much appreciated.

[See this corresponding plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OeKEdH3GtHS9WTMcfpEF?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the `table`-tag. The browser rearranges the html of the `myTable` template before angularjs renders it. This is happening because the html is not valid.

To solve this issue you can change the restrict property of the `myRow`-directive to `'A'` and use the directive like this:

```
...
'<tbody>',
    '<tr my-row ng-repeat="query in queries track by $index"',
        'query="query">',
    '</tr>',
'</tbody>',
...
```

This way the browser sees valid html and it works like it should be.

Here is the fixed **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUZVzKoZ2y8yCM0vAPJu?p=preview)**.