# Creating table row angular 1 components with migration to 2 in mind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, migration, angularjs-components

> [AngularJS nested directives are inserted outside their supposed parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27448789/3713032)

Using Angular 1.4 I hit the same same problem - but I'm also trying to create the rows as Angular 2 components, so I can not use "replace: true".

Will this be a problem at all when migrating from 1 to 2?
And if so, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class or attribute selector instead

```
@Component({
  selector: '[myTr]'
  template: `<td></td>`
})
export class MyTr {}
```

and then use it like

```
<tr myTr></tr>
```